# Globally modify left part URL in MVC 4 / 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

I am using IIS 8.5 with MVC4 and MVC5.

Let´s assume that I have two websites where the URL of the first (WS1) is:
http://myapp.example.com

and the second website (WS2) URL is:
http://myapp.example.com/sub
(and is located on another port to which I want to forward)

Now, my problem is that all URLs generated by MVC (links etc) will use the left part of the URL and remove /sub within that application. Let´s say for instance that in WS2 I want to redirect the user to http://myapp.example.com/sub/login but it will become http://myapp.example.com/login instead.

I have tried IIS URL rewrites but it will only work first-time request that actually contain the /sub part, the URLs generated by MVC of course remains erroneously without the /sub part.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite">
      <match url="^Sub/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://myapp.example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Response Status Update" preCondition="ResponseStatus" stopProcessing="true">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="^/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="/Sub/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteRelativePaths" preCondition="IsHTML">
      <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)" negate="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/Sub/.*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="/Sub/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="IsHTML">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
      </preCondition>
      <preCondition name="ResponseStatus">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3[0-9][0-9]" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

My question is how I can accomplish this. Using another subdomain is not an option.